# Which of the browser(s) will render display:run-in correctly?

Tags: css

1. IE7 & FF2.0
2. IE8 & Opera 9+
3. IE7 only
4. IE8 & FF3.5
5. IE7 & Safari

I encountered this question in a quiz. Don't have all browser to experiment with. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry to raise this type of question here. I would have referred 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html
Thanks Peter-Paul Koch for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html):

- IE8 (as IE8) and Opera 9.6.2 and 10 will render it correctly;
- Safari 3/4, Chrome 1+ and Konqueror render it incorrectly; and
- other browsers do not render it at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. NO & NO
2. YES & YES
3. NO
4. YES & NO
5. NO & YES*

*Safari supports run-in when it occurs before an element with display: inline. This should not happen. So technically, it is supported, but has issues.